# RxJava call returns NetworkOnMainThreadException while I've set subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

Tags: android, rx-java2

Based on my underestanding of RxJava, `sendMessage()` must be executed on background io thread and its result seen on Android main thread. However, `sendMessage()` method seems to be run on Android Main thread anyways and my app crashes (I catch it in `catch (e: Exception)`) due to `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

This is my code:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.company.oplogger.Logger
import com.company.optikbtv.utility.applySingleAsync
import com.company.optikbtv.utility.defaultErrorFun
import com.uber.autodispose.android.lifecycle.AndroidLifecycleScopeProvider
import com.uber.autodispose.lifecycle.autoDisposable
import io.reactivex.Single
import org.koin.core.parameter.parametersOf
import org.koin.standalone.KoinComponent
import org.koin.standalone.inject
import java.io.IOException
import java.net.*

const val UDP_HOST = "10.0.2.2" // Localhost
const val UDP_PORT = 3042

class EASViewModel : ViewModel(), KoinComponent {

    private val logger: Logger by inject { parametersOf(this) }
    private lateinit var scopeProvider: AndroidLifecycleScopeProvider
    private val socket = DatagramSocket()

    fun startEAS() {
        sendMessage(socket, UDP_HOST, UDP_PORT)
            .compose(applySingleAsync())
            .doOnDispose { logger.d("Disposing subscription from the EASViewModel.startEAS()") }
            .autoDisposable(scopeProvider)
            .subscribe({
                logger.d("on Subscribe: $it")
            }, defaultErrorFun)
    }

    private fun sendMessage(socket: DatagramSocket, host: String, port: Int) : Single<Boolean> {
        val throwable: Throwable
        val message = "Hello"
        val hostAddress = InetAddress.getByName(host)

        val buf = message.toByteArray()
        try {
            logger.d("Current thread: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            val packet = DatagramPacket(buf, buf.size, hostAddress, port)
            socket.send(packet)
            logger.d("Sent message: $message")

            return Single.just(true)
        } catch (e: SocketException) {
            throwable = e
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: UnknownHostException) {
            throwable = e
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throwable = e
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throwable = e          // <=== This is where I get Exception
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return Single.error(throwable)
    }
}
```

This is `applySingleAsync` that has composed in above code:

```
fun <T> applySingleAsync(): SingleTransformer<T, T> {
    return SingleTransformer { observable ->
        observable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    }
}
```

I have no idea what is the problem exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sendMessage()` is a function that executes synchronously as you're calling it synchronously.

It would only be the `Single` you create that would execute on IO thread but you only have constant value `Single.just()` (and `Single.error()`) to return so there's really no code to execute on IO scheduler.

You would actually have to supply a code block to construct your `Single` from. For example, wrap your code in `Single.fromCallable { }` instead of using `Single.just()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @laalto. `Single.just(true)` is being called after `socket.send(packet)` which is the place error happens. Therefore, `Single.just(true)` won't be called. Another thing is, based on my underestanding, `sendMessage()` must be called in io thread as I set `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`. This is what have confused me.

Comment: Yes, there's an exception before `Single.just()` is reached. `subscribeOn()` etc. affects the observable you return, not the code that creates it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your explanation. I did a quick search and found https://www.lvguowei.me/post/rxjava-fromcallable-vs-defer/ as refrence. So, this is my fix for those who have similar misunderestanding: `Single.fromCallable { sendMessage(socket, UDP_HOST, UDP_PORT) }`